# Having trouble recreating node.js HMAC in python

Tags: python, node.js, hmac

I am trying to recreate this node.js script in python:

```
const { createHmac } = require('crypto');

const generateHMAC = (uuid2, uuid1, timestamp) => {
  return createHmac('sha256', uuid2.substring(0, 10))
    .update(uuid2 + uuid1 + timestamp)
    .digest('hex');
}

const uuid1 = '00210078-008a-00b3-00fc-005e009b00a7'
const uuid2 = '00eb0079-0033-00a2-00ab-005c003900b5'
const timestamp = '1643438223104'

const hmac = generateHMAC(uuid2, uuid1, timestamp)
console.log(hmac)
```

I am getting a 'TypeError: Strings must be encoded before hashing' error. However I am not too sure if I am even on the right track. My current python script:

```
import random, os, gmpy2, hmac, time, hashlib, base64

def generate_hmac(uuid2, uuid1, timestamp):
    message = uuid2 + uuid1 + timestamp

    key = uuid2[0:10]

    hmac_result = hmac.new(bytes(key, encoding='utf-8'), message, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
    print(hmac_result)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uuid1 = '00210078-008a-00b3-00fc-005e009b00a7'
    uuid2 = '00eb0079-0033-00a2-00ab-005c003900b5'
    timestamp = '1643438223104'

    generate_hmac(uuid2=uuid2, uuid1=uuid1, timestamp=timestamp)
```

- Please forgive the messy imports, this is just a section of the script.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to solve this issue, heres my result:

```
def generate_hmac(uuid2, uuid1, timestamp):
    message = uuid2 + uuid1 + timestamp
    messageBytes = bytes(message.encode('utf-8'))

    key = uuid2[0:10]
    keyBytes = bytes(key.encode('utf-8'))

    hmac_result = hmac.new(keyBytes, messageBytes, hashlib.sha256).hexdigest()
```

I was not encoding my message and key prior to use in the hmac.new() func.

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helped you.